# Google Maps Api v3 - new MarkerClusterer works too slow?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

to create map clusterer, i use:

```
markerClustererGPC = new MarkerClusterer(myMap.map, markersGPC, GPCOptions);
```

but sometimes it does not works, and markerClustererGPC is sometimes undefined.

i search on this problem, and realise that (it looks like) server is sometimes too fast, and cluster is not defined due to that.

if server is a bit older (slower), it works without problems.

am i right about this? what can i do to avoid this problem, to make my code proper to work on any server?

Answer (score 3):

i think because google map is not loaded completed so your map is unidentified.
Try add this:

> var isLoad = false;
>
> google.maps.event.addListener(map,'tilesloaded',
>   function () {
>
> if (!isLoad) {
>
> ```
> isLoad = true;
> LoadClusterFunction();
> ```
>
> }
>
> });

after your call for creating map (map is variable for google map)